# UI virtualization implementation details. How to implement it?

Tags: algorithm, user-interface, scroll, virtualization

I know that several frameworks implement UI virtualization, like C# WPF, Qt QML and Aurelia JS.

I understood the basic idea of how virtualization works and how items are recycled during scrolling.

Given that i struggle to understand:

- how can the viewport know which item need to be drawed given it's offset?
- how can the viewport calculate it's real dimensions if the items could have different heights?

The real problem is variable heights (or widths) in the item painted during scrolling. In fact if the height of the painted controls is fixed everything is simple:

- Content size is numItems*itemHeight (or numItems * itemWidth)
- The first item painted in the view is calculate by ViewPortOffset / ItemHeight. For example if the Viewport has size 100x100 and it's current offset is 200 and itemHeight is 10 than the first item to be painted is item 20.

Are there any kind of resources or blogs for learning how to solve this problem with variable heights/widths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my [Sciter Engine](http://sciter.com) I have an example of virtual scrollable list of items having variable heights:

[image]

with or without kinetic (animated) scroll support.

Implementation is quite straightforward, check {sciter-sdk}/samples/ideas/virtual-list/vertical.htm demo and [tapev.tis implementation](https://github.com/c-smile/sciter-sdk/blob/master/samples/ideas/virtual-list/tapev.tis).

It uses sliding yet fixed buffer of DOM elements - at any given moment of time only `const BUFFER_SIZE = 20;` of elements are loaded into the view. And so it can be used to scroll over recordsets of unlimited length.

It works pretty well but with one obvious limitation - no scrollbar. To be precise: no scrollbar that reflects items/content dimensions as the whole recordset is not available at the rendering time. But you can have scrollbar that approximates that - e.g. scrollbar slider size reflects number of items seen and its position - index of first item in the view.

Comment: mind to explain a little bit how the how the 

"
var (scroll_left,scroll_top, scroll_right, scroll_bottom) = this.scroll(#rect);
"

works and delta.

From what you say you basically could draw scrollbar only for the loaded content items. But couldn't the scrollbar reflects the total number of items and the current visualized one? in other words the scrollbar doesn't makes you navigate through the content but through the items (this requires that you know the total number of items but not their size)

Comment: For `this.scroll()` check this http://sciter.com/docs/content/sciter/Element.htm#method-scroll 

As of delta... when you have undefined/unknown content height the only option for scrolling is to use relative scroll position.

When you need to scroll container up for YYYpx you a) insert more dom element/items in front of your buffer, b) measure their height and c) set container's scroll position to currentScrollPos + newItemsHeight - YYYpx.

Comment: ok now the scroll method is clear. Given that other engines both have virtualization and show scrollbars that more or less reflects the total content height. Probably this is done by some kind of aproximation, do you know any kind of implementation of such heuristics?

Comment: About "know any kind of implementation of such heuristics". We did it in Evernote v. 2.0  : http://sciter.com/images/en2.jpg . Notes there were rendered in "endless notes tape" - list of HTML micro-documents. As you see it had navigation scrollbar that reflected topmost rendered note in the whole set. Second scrollbar-alike thing is a scroller element that allowed to chose scrolling speed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that most UI virtualizations rely on having items the same size.

If you need your objects to have unpredictable size than one idea comes to my mind. For each element store somewhere the offset (px position) where it begins. I think the best would be an array of positions.

For example you have vertical view with 10 objects sized 10x10, 20x20, ... , 100x100. They will start in positions: 0, 10, 30, 60, ...
Let's say your view currently displays from `y1 = 15` to `y2 = 40`. Now you need to render all objects that start in the position greater than `y1` and less than `y2` and also one more from each side. So you will need to render second, third and forth object.

Of course it is very important how will you store the starting positions and what algorithm will you use to find the values. If you need the view to contain a lot of items then you should also think about the language you will implement the algorithm in.

Comment: It cannot work this way it think... because that means that you already know all your items sizes and that goes against the idea of virtualization